# Installing SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 Maintenance Pack

Tags: software-installation, sco

I have had so many issues on how to download, extract and install this software on SCO. And I'm sure there are loads of people having or had the same issue as I am having.

So the question is, how do I install software in SCO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this on the [SCO FTP site](ftp://ftp.sco.com/pub/openserver5/507/mp/osr507mp5/osr507mp5.htm#rn507mp_install).

To **unzip** the TAR folder: `tar xvf osr507mp5_vol.tar`

To **install** the Maintenance Pack: You will need to go to the SCOADMIN (login as root) and Install media. Type `/usr/spool/patches/osr507mp5` in the path.

All is explained in the Documentation in that link I added.